# SQL Query If Statement?

Tags: php, sql, database

I have two fields in a legacy database. I want to query one of them, but its often `null`, In this case is there like an `if` statement `like Where if field_a !== null { field_a='Value' } else { field_b='Value' }`

My Question is, is there a way to do this in sql itself or would i have to do two queries, one to check if null, then an if statement in my logic?

Comment: sql `case` statement, mysql `if`, etc... lots of ways. no need for multiple queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can capture the logic like this:

```
where field_a = 'Value' or (field_a is NULL and field_b = 'Value')
```

or more simply as:

```
where field_a = 'Value' or field_b = 'Value'
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've never see `as` used this way -- can you provide a link so I can read about it?

Comment: @onedaywhen I think it should be `AND` but I would never say Gordon is wrong -- every time I have in the past I've been wrong.

Comment: @Hogan: yeah... maybe it should be "field_a is to null as field_b is to 'value'" :)